# String to jQuery.function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

What's the simplest way to call a string method with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)?

Comment: FWIW: You are not converting anything. There are just two ways to access properties of objects: Dot notation and bracket notation. The bracket notation expects a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to call a method whose name is stored in a string.

If that's the case, you should use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) *instead of* (not *in addition to*) dot notation, and delimit the literal string with quotes:

```
$["STRINGVALUE"]();
```

You can also use the variable you defined initially, without quotes:

```
$[myFunction]();
```

Comment: May this error be outdated? I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. Have gotten it working with eval(STRINGVALUE+'()').

Comment: @user, it looks like your problem is not the same. You want to call a function named `STRINGVALUE`, but cept0 wants to invoke a *jQuery method* named `STRINGVALUE`.

Comment: A function being a user defined function, while a jQuery method is a function defined within the $. namespace?

Comment: @user, more or less, yes. Technically, `$.fn` also comes into play for jQuery methods, but in this particular case the questioner indeed wants to call a method exposed by the `$` object directly (such methods are akin to static methods in other languages).